# CLLocationManagerDelegate fail by try to get user current location

Tags: swift, core-location

I try to get user current location (blue dot like google map) and also latitude and longitude of user current location

ps. I already add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in info.plist

I try this

```
private var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
private var currentLocation: CLLocation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self as! CLLocationManagerDelegate
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    // Check for Location Services

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    defer { currentLocation = locations.last }

    if currentLocation == nil {
        // Zoom to user location
        if let userLocation = locations.last {
            let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 2000, 2000)
            mapView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

But the error appear when that page was open by this line

```
locationManager.delegate = self as! CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

> Could not cast value of type 'tramsimulator.ViewController' (0x10b542c28) to 'CLLocationManagerDelegate

Comment: Show your `class ViewController` line.

Comment: When you need to force cast `self` to the desired delegate, that quite often means you haven't made your class conform to the protocol you wanted to. Please include the code you use to declare conformation to `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.